# How to create a 120V-175V Variable Frequency Generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

I am dealing with a system that requires me to drive a capacitive load at 120V-175Vrms, AC square/sine wave at two frequencies: 50Hz and 2000 Hz @ Ipeak = 100mA. I am currently trying to find the best way to achieve this.

I had originally used a HV driver chip that had a supply of 300V, modulate the output to create a 0-300V square wave, high pass filter it, and finally send it to my load. The issue with it was how I generated my power supply. I had used a voltage doubler + voltage divider to obtain 300V from 120VAC in. As you all know, voltage dividers are terrible for usage a power supply from a variable load.

My next plan was to instead use a high voltage op-amp with square wave input, and configure it like a comparator to create a AC square wave, which would drive my load. The issue is that again the power. Here I tried to implement a SMPS from 12V to 175V, but the problem was the efficiency was terrible and thus I could not find any economical 12V power supplies to adequately drive my load.

So my question to all of you: is there a better way to generate an AC sine/square wave of 120-175Vrms @I=100mA? Or is there easy solutions to the problems I have faced in my implementations?

Comment: Do you have a transformer you could use to step 120VAC up to feed your HV driver?

Comment: They still make linear supplies that go to 200V @0.1A.  Buy a bunch of 48V wall warts and put them in series?  Get a 48V supply and step it up.  Make a lower voltage and step up the output with a transformer.

Comment: Is this a one-off project, or something that you need to be able to produce in quantity? For a one-off, I would just feed the output of a laboratory function generator into a medium-sized (e.g., about 50W) audio power amplifier, and connect its output to a 1:10 power transformer (AKA 12.6 V filament transformer, used in reverse).

Comment: @DaveTweed, I do like the output transformer solution. (Keep everything at cheap ~30V. @~1A) But how does a 60Hz AC transformer respond at 2k Hz... I'm guessing there are better and worse.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: It'll be kind of lossy, but remember, transformers with laminated cores are widely used in audio applications (20 Hz - 20 kHz). The better ones will have thinner laminations, of course. If you can liberate a suitable output transformer from an old tube amplifier, it'll probably work somewhat better than a generic power transformer.

Comment: @DaveTweed This is not a one off and would be produced in quantity. The issue seems to be that all the SMPS solutions we design are grossly inefficient at 0.1A. Also the transformer solution is one of the SMPS we looked into (flyback transformer) but again it was too inefficient.

Comment: I think in that case, you need to be a little more specific about your requirements. What kind of accuracy and resolution do you need on the voltage levels? How much waveform distortion can you tolerate? What do you really need in terms of efficiency?